# Resolving dependencies related to 32 bit libraries on 64 bit

Tags: 64-bit, adobe-air

I am struggling to make a 32bit application (related to adobe AIR)
work on my 64bit Ubuntu system. The application starts fine but there
is no sound. After running the application from the terminal, I've
noticed the following error messages:

```
/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to load type module:
/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so
Gtk-WARNING **: /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-ibus.so: wrong
ELF class: ELFCLASS64
Gtk-WARNING **: Loading IM context type 'ibus' failed
Gtk-WARNING **: /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-ibus.so: wrong
ELF class: ELFCLASS64
Gtk-WARNING **: Loading IM context type 'ibus' failed
```

I suspect the following errors could be resolved by a careful
update/downgrade of some specific libraries in the ia32 package. Since
I am not a Linux expert I was wondering if someone could suggest me
some ways to try to fix the above error messages. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, the error means that it tries to load a 64 bits library which is impossible for a 32 bits applications. 32 bits libraries should be present in `/usr/lib32`.

Comment: Thank you for your response!
So how could I get rid of the error messages?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered. This will be closed. If this question is still valid, please add more detail and flag for it to be reopened.