# Is it OK to remove appmenu-gtk and install appmenu-gtk:i386?

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, multiarch

I wanted to eliminate some skype errors and by installing the `appmenu-gtk:i386` package the errors were gone!

These were the errors:

```
$ skype
/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

(skype:2841): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to load type module: /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so

/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

(skype:2841): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to load type module: /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so

/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

(skype:2841): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to load type module: /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so

/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

(skype:2841): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to load type module: /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so
```

The change was easy: `sudo apt-get install appmenu-gtk:i386`

I haven't noticed any "weird" outcome (yet). The good thing was that it cleared the skype errors. But I have my doubts.

Has anyone tried something similar? Removing `appmenu-gtk` and installing `appmenu-gtk:i386` on a 64-bit system? Could it break any applications?

Similar question: [Resolving dependencies related to 32 bit libraries on 64 bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37571/resolving-dependencies-related-to-32-bit-libraries-on-64-bit)

Comment: It would be nice to know which Skype errors for the benefit of other users.

Comment: @ToDo the errors that show in the terminal output, the "libappmenu.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64" messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer to my own question: A lot of programs use this package, but none of them showed any problems.

The only program that was crashing constantly was hp-gui indicator.